Laravel Eloquent - Using "with(..)" query via anonymous function always returns array
Apologies if this is a duplicate but if it is I can't find it! I'll try to be as descriptive as possible to help with Google search.
How does Laravel handle scenarios where "with" uses an anonymous function and returns only the object, similar to how first() works meaning it would return an object as only one row is requested; whereas get() returns an array of objects. When using Model::with([relationship => function () use ($example) { $q->where('foo', 'bar')->first(); }]); I can't get it to return the object, instead I am given an array with 1 value.
Here is a more accurate code sample:
// get planet
$planet = Planet::with([
    'population' => function ($q) use ($tick) {
        $q->where('tick', '<=', $tick)->orderBy('tick', 'desc')->first();
    }, 
    'resources' => function ($q) use ($tick) {
        $q->where('tick', '<=', $tick)->orderBy('tick', 'desc')->first();
    }, 
    'vessels', 
    'galaxy',
    'alliance'
])->where('uid', $id)->where('tick', '<=', $tick)->orderBy('tick', 'desc')->first();
        

I feel I'm missing something basic! Thanks in advance.
I have tried first() and take(1) and no joy. It returns an array with 1 object, rather than just the object, if I supply first().

Your relationship always returns a collection (not an array). The first() or get() should not be in the query build. You can use the ->first() If you are using this in a blade template you can call ->first() on the collection that is returned

So to be clear every time I do a query I would have to call $entity->relation->first()?

If you defined population or resources  as a one-to-many relationship then it has to be returned as a collection. You can take a look at one of many  relationships in case that does what you need. You'd need to define new relationships for this to work

Good point. Will take a look. Thank you.

Create an answer it was the case.
